# How to Obtain (Extract) eBay Listing EAN which is not Visible (multi-variation listing?

Tags: ebay-api

wanted to know if there's a way to obtain the ean used by seller for a product listing on eBay, the ean does currently show up on eBay's item specifics area if its a multi-variation listing (only shows up if its a single product listing), so is there a way to obtain the ean used for a listing, here's an example of a listing which I would like to obtain the ean used: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Luxury-Magnetic-Flip-Cover-Stand-Wallet-Leather-Case-For-Apple-iPhone-Models-/172423423931?var=&hash=item28253ca7bb:m:mUL-SeQQB128hGq-rt62LJw

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [GetItem](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html) operation in the Trading API. Below is an example XML request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemRequest 
  xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <ItemID>172423423931</ItemID>
  <OutputSelector>Item.Variations.Variation.VariationProductListingDetails.EAN</OutputSelector>
</GetItemRequest>
```

A sample of the response from the API is below. The EAN information is contained in the `Item.Variations.Variation.VariationProductListingDetails.EAN` field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse 
  xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2017-02-17T10:12:13.699Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>991</Version>
  <Build>E991_CORE_API_18167430_R1</Build>
  <Item>
    <Variations>
      <Variation>
        <VariationProductListingDetails>
          <EAN>0702865347275</EAN>
        </VariationProductListingDetails>
      </Variation>
      <Variation>
        <VariationProductListingDetails>
          <EAN>0702865347275</EAN>
        </VariationProductListingDetails>
      </Variation>
    </Variations>
  </Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```